# app.get works, app.use does not

Tags: node.js, url, express, router

How come this is working:

```
app.get(/\/new\/(.*)/, function (req, res) {

    console.log(req.params[0]);
    res.json({site: req.params[0]});

});
```

but the same code won't if i use `app.use()`.

```
const app = require("express")();
const error = require("./routes/error");

app.use(/\/new\/(.*)/,error);
```

**error.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();


router.get("/",function(req,res){
    console.log(req.params[0])
    res.json({site:req.params[0]})
});




module.exports = router;
```

It just logs undefined to the console in this case, but in the first case it returns everything typed after the "new" route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to implement the same using app.use(), you have to modify your code slightly. Do the following changes:

In app.js:

```
app.use('/new',error);
```

and in error.js ,

```
router.get(/(.*)/,function(req,res){
    console.log(req.params[0])
    res.json({site:req.params[0]})
});
```

Try this and let me know

Comment: @JohnNoob Let me know if this worked for you. And read more about app.use() and app.get() to understand the usage of both

Comment: Thank you very much buddy.. After this project I plan to dig deep on them ! :D

Comment: Good job @PankajkumarPanigrahi